# custom order and display foreach PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Thanks to the many folks who help us out here on Stackoverflow.  You all are awesome!  Now to the question.  I've got an array for the following values: "duck", "chicken","egg", "pork", "steak", "beef", "fish", "shrimp", "deer", and "lamb."

I've gotten the list to display in Alphabetical order.  This is a dynamic array, so it may not always have all these values or be in that order.  I'd like to have "Steak" always appear first with "Top Choice" next to it, while keeping the rest in alphabetical order with "Available for Order" next to them.

Here's what I've got thus far with $meat_items as the array:

```
foreach($meat_items as $meat_item)
     echo $meat_item . ' Available for Order <br>';
```

I should clarify: Steak may NOT always be a part of the array.

Comment: "it may not always have all these values or be in that order." But will it always have "Steak"? What exactly is special about "Steak" that you want to put it first in the list?

Comment: It may not always have Steak either.  I need that to stand out since it's one of the top choices of that meat category, rather than be at the bottom of the list.  The rest need to be alphabetized.

Comment: Couldn't you just remove "Steak" from the array, echo it, and THEN echo everything from the array?

Comment: Is there any simpler way to just select a value in the array to display first, and then continue to the rest?

Comment: @David it doesn't get any simpler than my answer, see below.

Comment: If you're populating the array from a SQL select, you can use "ORDER BY name = 'Steak' DESC, name".

Comment: @David Check out my update (see below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you always want steak to appear first, hard code it:

```
if (in_array("steak", $meat_items)) {
    `echo "Steak: Top Choice";`
}
```

Sort your array alphabetically:

```
sort($meat_items);
```

Then loop through your array, echoing all items *except* the steak:

```
foreach ($meat_items as $meat_item) {
    if ( "steak" != $meat_item ) {
        echo $meat_item . ' Available for Order<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeCummins add in sort(). he still wants the rest of the items sorted.

Comment: I should clarify: Steak may NOT always be a part of the array.

Comment: @FinalForm: He said he already worked that out, but I added it to make you happy.

Comment: @David: In my code, this is not a problem. However, do you want the hard-coded value to display only if steak is present in the array, or in all cases?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  I'd like it to display only if steak is present in the array.  I thought there might be a statement I could use within the foreach, but it looks like that's not the case.

Comment: @David: See the answer update for code to check the array for the existence of steak.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($meat_items['steak']))
{
    echo 'Steak Top Choice <br >';   
    unset($meat_items['steak']);
}

sort($meat_items);

foreach($meat_items as $meat_item)
     echo $meat_item . ' Available for Order <br>';
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis in the `unset()` function.

Comment: I should clarify: Steak may NOT always be a part of the array.

Answer (score 0):

A more general purpose way to do this is to tell PHP how to sort the items, by defining a sorting "comparison" that prefers the "top choices", and then passing it to `usort`.

I don't really know PHP, but something like:

```
function prefer_top($a, $b) {
    /* We can modify this array to specify whatever the top choices are. */
    $top_choices = array('Steak');
    /* If one of the two things we're comparing is a top choice and the other isn't,
       then it comes first automatically. Otherwise, we sort them alphabetically. */
    $a_top = in_array($a, $top_choices);
    $b_top = in_array($b, $top_choices);
    if ($a_top && !$b_top) { return -1; }
    if ($b_top && !$a_top) { return 1; }
    if ($a == $b) { return 0; }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($meat_items, "prefer_top");

// and then output them all in order as before.
```